# Can't load PHP but downloaded as .php fie

Tags: php, apache

I am using .PHP file and I have already installed php module by `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`, and `sudo a2enmod php5` to start the service.  I assigned a route for the `index.php` file, but when I was accessing the route, the browser downloaded the `index.php` file instead of open/execute it.

I googled this issue it says I should add a handler so the php module can handle this type of file and execute it.  The method is open the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf` and add a line

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

and I tried this ,it still didn't work.

I am wondering do you know any other better solutions for this situation?

Comment: Did you restart the server after you did all of that?

Comment: Does your server run?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I am restarting my server now.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I tried restarting my server and it still didn't work, it's still downloading the php file.

Comment: @pbaldauf Yes my server runs well